# swiper 3.3.1 main image and thumbnail not in sync

Tags: synchronization, thumbnails, swiper.js

swiper 3.3.1
issue reproduced on: chrome, firefox (haven't checked other browsers)

As I click on the right arrow and reach the 5th image, the thumbnails slide to the wrong image (main image and thumbnail image are not in sync anymore).

The problem disappears if I set centeredSlides: true (but I want it to work without centering)

can anyone help?
here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Paofiddle/5jzk0ojq/4/
P.S it doesn't seem to work at all in the "run code snippet" thingy in here but you can see the issue via the fiddle link.

```js
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 1
    });
    var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        slideToClickedSlide: true
    });
    galleryTop.params.control = galleryThumbs;
    galleryThumbs.params.control = galleryTop;
```

```css
    html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #000;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
    .gallery-top {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs {
        height: 20%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/1)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/2)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/3)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/4)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/5)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/6)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/7)"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/1)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/2)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/3)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/4)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/5)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/6)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature/7)"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/5jzk0ojq/70/

```
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 10,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    loop:true,
    loopedSlides:3
});
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    loop:true,
    loopedSlides:3
});
galleryTop.params.control = galleryThumbs;
galleryThumbs.params.control = galleryTop;
```

loop the slider, slideperview should be the same for loopedslides

Answer (score -1):

Try using centeredSlides.

https://jsfiddle.net/5jzk0ojq/10/

```
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 1
    });
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        centeredSlides: true,
        slideToClickedSlide: true
});
galleryTop.params.control = galleryThumbs;
galleryThumbs.params.control = galleryTop;
```